# Startup splash screen flashes then black screen

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, xorg

I just tried upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04.

Everything went smoothly until the very end when it gave a message saying that there was a problem with the installation, but it still completed and told me to restart the computer to complete the installation.

After I restarted, it went to the grub screen fine. When I selected Ubuntu it started loading, flashed the Ubuntu splash screen for a second and then goes to a black screen and appears to freeze with no disk activity.

If I reboot, the same thing happens. If I try rebooting in recovery mode from the grub screen and then selecting `resume normal boot`, it gets me to a working command prompt.

I tried running 'startx' from the command prompt but that fails also. In the `Xorg.0.log` file it says, among other things, that:

```
Failed to load module 'Intel' (module requirement mismatch, 0)
```

And also, it fails to load the modules 'vesa' and 'fbdev'.

I really have no idea what that means, but I'm guessing the error has something to do with a mismatch with my Intel video card.

I am running it on a [Compaq Presario V6000](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/ho/WF06a/12139188-78299199-78308301-78308301-78308301-78867421.html) laptop.

Would appreciate any help, as I have no clue what to do next.

I've searched the forums, but I can't find anything that works.

The computer was running absolutely fine on 10.10 and now all of a sudden this fails on upgrade!

Comment: I have this problem too - something to with the video drivers - I am still trawling to find a solution

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).